# How do I access properties of a keypress event in ClojureScript using channels?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Using ClojureScript, I'm trying to take action when someone presses `enter` in a textfield, and ignore other keys. So I need to be able to discriminate between different keypresses.

For reference, my `ns` in my `.cljs` is:

```
(ns calculator.calculator
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])
  (:require [goog.dom :as dom]
            [goog.events :as events]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [put! chan <!]]
            [clojure.string :as string]))
```

My html has a input element `<input id="data-entry-box"></input>`. I set up the listener this way:

```
(defn listen [el type]
  (let [out (chan)]
    (events/listen el type
                   (fn [e] (put! out e)))
    out))

(let [keypresses (listen (dom/getElement "data-entry-box") "keypress")]
  (go (while true
        (let [key-event (<! keypresses)
              char-code (.-charCode key-event)]
          (.log js/console (str "The character code is " char-code))
          (.log js/console (str "The key is " (.-key key-event)))
          (.log js/console (str "The event is " (.-event key-event)))
          (.log js/console (str "Or the event is " (:event key-event)))
          (if (= char-code
                 13)
            (handle-submit))))))
```

After compiling it, loading the page, and pressing enter in the input element, I get the following in the console:

```
"The character code is 13"
"The key is "
"The event is "
"Or the event is "
```

This is fine; I can check what the key is by looking up the ASCII value -- but I shouldn't have to. I'd like to directly access the character pressed.

If I put a breakpoint, I can see that there's an `.event` property, and that property has a further property `.key`. But I can't access it, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The property on the keypress is not actually called `.event`; it's called `.event_`. Note the trailing underscore. So we access it with `(.-event_ key-event)`, as follows:

```
(let [keypresses (listen (dom/getElement "data-entry-box") "keypress")]
  (go (while true
        (let [key-event (<! keypresses)
              key-pressed (.-key (.-event_ key-event))]
          (.log js/console (str "The key pressed was " key-pressed))
          (if (= key-pressed
                 "Enter")
            (handle-submit))))))
```

This code prints: "The key pressed was Enter".

Note that javascript doesn't have character literals, so what `(.-key (.-event_ key-event))` returns is a string `"Enter"`.

Comment: show your listen method, I don't think property named event_. Which browser do you use? Put a complete working example code. thx

Comment: @edbond I edited it into the question, and (at least in Firefox 31 and Chromium 36) the property is definitely named `event_`. Unfortunately, in Chromium, the sub-property is not `key`, but `keyIdentifier`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at mousetrap code - https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/blob/master/mousetrap.js

It's common to use keycode or map it manually to "Enter".

Also I have a big doubt event_ is a common property, you can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

Comment: `event_` looks like it's a ClojureScript thing (or a Google Closure thing) -- it's assigned in the javascript generated by the ClojureScript compiler.

Comment: Then you shouldn't rely on it. In advanced compilation it will be munged to something like 'A' and your code will not work.